# URI Routing Help CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, uri

I am new to codeigniter, infact using it first time. I am editing a script developed using CodeIgniter. It is GroupScript - clone of famous Groupon. In this script, there is a facility to select different cities. By default, links to different cities are like :

`domain.com/frontend/profile/selectCity/[city_id]`

I want some uri routing example so that i can redirect domain.com/[city_id] to

`domain.com/frontend/profile/selectCity/[city_id]`

I studied some examples that helped also. The best far i could get was

`domain.com/index.php/[city_id]`

was being redirected to

`domain.com/frontend/profile/selectCity/[city_id]`

Code used was : `$route[’(:num)’] = “frontend/profile/selectCity/$1”;`

I am not able to eliminate the `index.php` in url. Any help would be appreciated. If i could eliminate `index.php` stuff from url then I am done.

Demo groupscript is here to understand what i expect : demo.groupscript.net

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the routing feature, but removing the index.php can be done with .htaccess files (if you are on apache). See the section titled **Removing the index.php file** in [this part of the user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would want something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|javascript|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This will redirect all request within your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set the default index to '' in config.php under:

"If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this variable so that it is blank."

Answer (score 0):

Remove ***"index.php"*** to make it blank in your config.php file. The default file name will be removed from the URL then

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```